# What Korean IME can I use on WindowsXP for my specific needs?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, keyboard, ime, korean

I'm currently using Korean Input System (IME 2002), my problem is that it gives me [Hangul Compatibility Jamo (U+3130 – U+318F)](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/hangul_compatibility_jamo.html) instead of regular [Hangul Jamo(U+1100 – U+11FF).](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/hangul_jamo.html) 
They look the same to me but they are unfortunately unequal (as tested in my programming code).

Reason:
I normally wouldn't have qualms about this, but Compatibility Jamo doesn't normalize correctly using NormalizeString.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're be able to create the keyboard layout you want with *Microsoft Layout Keyboard Creator*

MSLKC:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665

GHacks article on MSLKC: http://www.ghacks.net/2011/08/08/microsoft-keyboard-layout-creator/

(I tested MSLKC only with Latin alphabet: I hope this utility work well with your awesome Hangul alphabet!)

Hope this help. Let us know.  :)